# Reliability vs Accuracy vs Precision vs Validity

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis

I am trying to distinguish the difference between Validity, Accuracy, Precision and Reliability. I understand that accuracy is a measure of how close something is to the true value and precision is how close repeated measurements are, but what are validity and reliability? It seems to me that precision and reliability are used interchangeably as well as accuracy and validity. Is this true?

Comment: This question may be better suited for engineering, as V&V (validation and verification) are ISO9000 concepts for products or systems. Reliability engineering is a whole nother thing where you estimate how reliabiable a system is; e.g., a Mars Rover is spec'd to last 2 years (with 99.7% probability) so irl they always last much longer.

Comment: @JEB If the question arises in the context of quantum measurements or something like that, it is certainly more physics than engineering. More context would be helpful.

Comment: In the past we had plenty of discussions about the issue that theoretical topics are discussed on this site in great depth (despite their close relationship to mathematics), while topics  discussing experimental physics get pushed to "engineering websites". Beside the fact that I never found a good "engineering website" discussing many experimental physics topics, I feel that it is important that we discuss these topics here on physics SE.

Answer (score 3):

Say, our aim is to measure the diameter of an object. The true (unknown) diameter of this object is 5mm. We take our ruler and take 10 measurements, $\{x_1, \ldots, x_{10}\}$.

- **Accuracy** describes the difference between the **true value** (=5mm) and the the sample average value of repeated measurements
  $\bar x = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i$. E.g. we could buy calibrated "standards" of certain lengths and a well-defined  uncertainties to estimate the accuracy of your measurement device across our needed value range.
- **Precision** describes the variability of repeated measurements. It is defined as the sample standard deviation,
  $s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{10-1}\sum_{i=1}^{10} (x_i - \bar x)^2}$. Note that different types of precisions exists, and that they are used if we wish to describe the limitations in greater detail -- e.g. reproducibility, repeatability.
- **Validity** describes the ability to measure what we initially **intended** to measure. E.g. if the object consists of a material with a "large" thermal expansion coefficient and we do not document the temperature at which the measurement is taken, our readings could become useless. The same is true if our ruler possesses only marks with a distance of 10mm. In either case we would argue that the measurement is not valid. To my personal knowledge there exists no statistical exact definition of the term *validity*.  Thus, I have only  used the term "validity" in an informal manner.
- **Reliability** does not have an exact definition -- to my personal knowledge. It is considered to be the "overall consistency of a measure". I would argue that a measure possess a high reliability, if it is (1) repeatable, (2) reproducible by others, and (3) consistent by other measurement methods  -- e.g. if we would replace the ruler by an interferometer and obtain consistent results. However, again, I only used this term in an informal manner.

Hope this helps.